# django write signal handler as class (write class based django signal handlers)

Tags: python, django, django-signals

From django docs it is clear that we can write signals handlers as function.

```py
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from myapp.models import MyModel


@receiver(pre_save, sender=MyModel)
def my_handler(sender, **kwargs):
    ...
```

Is it possible to write the signal handlers as classes?
If yes HOW?

Answer (score 0):

```
YourClass(Inheritance):
    @receiver(pre_save, sender=MyModel)
    def __call__(self, sender, **kwargs):
        #your code
        return
```

And then when you want to use this class you would import it and write:

```
my_handler = YourClass()
```

So you then could include an instantiated version in your settings file or wherever you need it.

Something like this should be possible. But why may I ask?